# radio buttons, checkboxes, and textarea

Tags: html

I have to have 3 questions. One with radio button options, one with checkboxes and one with a textarea. The problem I am having is the questions all have to be on the same line with the choices below each of those questions. I used a table to get the questions on the same line but the problem I am having is I can't get the choices (radio button, checkboxes, and text area) under each appropriate question.

This is what I am receiving:

```
 Your question here: choice 1 choice 2. ques. here: c1, c2, c3, c4
```

I need this:

```
Your question here:       
Choice 1                                        
Choice 2
```

With the other 2 questions right beside that question in that format.

This is the html coding I'm using below:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td align="left">  Your question here:</td>     
    <td><input name="choice" type="radio" value="1" />Choice 1 </td>
    <br />
    <td><input name="choice" type="radio" value="2" checked="checked" />Choice 2</td>

    <td align="center"> Your question here:</td>
<br>
    <td><input name="choice" type="checkbox" value="choice1" />Choice 1</td>
<br>    
    <td><input name="choice" type="checkbox" value="choice2" />Choice 2</td>
<br>    
    <td><input name="choice" type="checkbox" value="choice3" />Choice 3</td>
<br>        
    <td><input name="choice" type="checkbox" value="choice4" checked="checked">Choice 4</td>

<td align="right"> Your question here:</td>
<td><br /><textarea name="other" rows="5" cols="35"></textarea></td> 


</tr>
</table>
```

I tried using  for each of the choices but it displayed both the questions and answers directly underneath one another and that's not what I need. It is driving me crazy because I know it is something simple. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried style this with any css? If yes add also this file. No one frome here give you solution from zero. You need do something before ask for help.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are using tables to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Nader's answer, but to answer your question, the reason the Choice appear next to the Questions appear next to each other as opposed to below the Question is because you are placing them in different cells (using ) within the SAME row (This makes a new column). If you were to make a second row and have 1 cell for all the choices, it would look something more like what you want.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td align="left" style="width:200px;">  Your question here:</td>  
    <td align="center" style="width:200px;"> Your question here:</td>  
    <td align="right" style="width:200px;"> Your question here:</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="left">
       <input name="choice" type="radio" value="1" />Choice 1 <br />
       <input name="choice" type="radio" value="2" checked="checked" />Choice 2</td>

    <td align="center">
       <input name="choice" type="checkbox" value="choice1" />Choice 1 <br /> 
       <input name="choice" type="checkbox" value="choice2" />Choice 2 <br/> 
       <input name="choice" type="checkbox" value="choice3" />Choice 3 <br />
       <input name="choice" type="checkbox" value="choice4" checked="checked" />Choice     4
    </td>

   <td><br /><textarea name="other" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea></td> 
</tr>
</table>
```

I added a little bit of styling to make it look a little more spaced out. It would be useful to draw the borders of the tables to see how things are spaced out.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would definitely advise that you use divs instead of tables (Personally, I am not convinced that tables are the appropriate solution), with that being said, have three divs, all floating left, with width 33% each and post the questions and the answers in them.
e.g.

```
<div>
Question 1<br/>
Choice 1 
Choice 2 
Choice 3
</div>

<div>
Question 2<br/>
Choice 1 
Choice 2 
Choice 3
</div>

<div>
Question 3<br/>
Choice 1 
Choice 2 
Choice 3
</div>

<style>
div{
    width:33%;
    float:left;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I didn't even think to use div tags.

Answer (score 0):

well with your tables as a solution I think you need this...

```
<table>
<tr>
        <td >  Your question here:</td>
        <br />  
        <td > Your question here:</td>
        <br />  
        <td > Your question here:</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <input name="choice" type="radio" value="1" />Choice 1 
        <br />  
        <input name="choice" type="radio" value="2" checked="checked" />Choice 2
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="choice" type="checkbox" value="choice1" />Choice 1
        <br />  
        <input name="choice" type="checkbox" value="choice2" />Choice 2
        <br />  
        <input name="choice" type="checkbox" value="choice3" />Choice 3
        <br />      
        <input name="choice" type="checkbox" value="choice4" checked="checked" />Choice 4
    </td>   
    <td>
        <textarea name="other" rows="5" cols="25"></textarea> 
    </td>
</tr>

</table>
```